# Is there a way to dynamically put value in html ID and class?

Tags: php, html

Long question short. I have a table which has ID and class values which I need to dynamically set.

Example: I need something like below:

```
<table class="table" id='<?php echo $count;?>'>
```

which will then pass a value from the href link

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger " id="remove-itinerary1" onclick="removeTable(<?php echo $count?>);">Remove</a></td>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: So, where is the php? What does $count hold? We need to see some logic.

Comment: What you want to say? You can use js or php. Don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: $count is a variable set during foreach loop for instance $count holds and integer value.

Comment: in table id value comes from onclick function perameter right?

Comment: the only thing i need to know is, is there a way to do : <table class="table" id='<?php echo $count;?>">  where i can echo ID value

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: is my syntax correct , i may be wrong using the prenthesis in the right way

Comment: You use `'` to open and `"` to close the `id` attribute.

Comment: @ Deepesh Thapa what exactly you want to achieve ? do you want this solution in jquery or php for dynamic id . explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can paas like that

```
<table class="table" id='<?php echo $count;?>'>
```

and also can use

```
<table class="table" id='table_<?php echo $count;?>'>
```

Comment: what is the use of using table_ prefix?

Comment: `id` cannot be referenced sometimes if they are integer. so add `prefix` and id

Comment: we can add prefix if required

Answer (score -1):

```
<table id='tid_<?php echo $count;?>'>
```

You need to assign some prefix so that you will not face problem while referencing the element using javascript.